# behaviours.js syntax (Leaflet Map)

Tags: javascript

An answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762984/leaflet-map-not-displayed-properly-inside-tabbed-panel) to a problem concerning [Leaflet Maps](http://leafletjs.com)

My question: How would I adapt this code (yellow border [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioaD7.jpg)) to the syntax of my-theme/my-theme.behaviours.js ?

I think it would begin:

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.any_name_here = {
```

or maybe

```
Drupal.behaviors.some_name_here = {
attach: function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
(function($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.leafletMap = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {

            $('body').once(function(){
                $(this).on('shown','#link3', function() { 
                    L.Util.requestAnimFrame(map.invalidateSize,map,!1,map._container);
                });

            });

        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

I've used .once() as you only want to bind this behavior once and the attach function will run on page load and every subsequent ajax request.

I found [this blog post](http://blog.amazeelabs.com/en/drupal-behaviors-quick-how) very useful on Drupal behaviors.

Comment: cool answer :). It cleared my concept much better Thanks.

Comment: @Felix Eve ok thanks - maybe this is a different issue but your behaviors.js seems to interfere with my jQuery UI tabs - Garland theme, no behaviors.js = http://tinyurl.com/k9n9y5p - omega theme with behaviors.js = http://tinyurl.com/k8egc3j